# Do a find but make its replace elsewhere

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to search for the variable name in a file and see if it is present in the format preceded and succeded by `<%=` and remove it if it is
eg.find the variable name from below(i.e invalidChars) and search if it is present in format `<%=invalidChars%>` and convert it to invalidChars

Example

```
var invalidChars = "getText('po.number.has.invalid.chars')" />';

/* Some random text */

alert('<%=invalidChars%> ')
```

I used `var` `(.*?\w+).*` to find variable name i.e `invalidChars` but now how do I replace this at the postion later in file  i.e convert `alert('<%=invalidChars%> ')` to `alert('invalidChars')` in a single or multiple operation ,how do I use this value obtained in my next search as I cant use find `<℅=$1=℅> with $1`

Comment: So what's the expected output?

Comment: You can't do that in a single find-and-replace. That's two operations you need to perform.

Comment: What is wrong with `<%=(\w+)%>`? See https://regex101.com/r/uB2vQ2/1
Or am I missing something completely?

Comment: @user3820163  you can use following to match ONLY word. `(?<=<%=)\w+(?=%>)`

Comment: hi I have edited my question , hope it makes easier to understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression replace.

- **Find what:** `(var\h+)([^\h=]+)(.*)<%=\2%>`
- **Replace with:** `\1\2\3\2`
- check in the lower left: **Regular expression** and **. matches newline**

Click a few times **Replace**, if you are sure it does what you want (also in complexer scenarios involving several variables): click **Replace All**. If it does not work use Undo.

In case that several var definitions and the position of their usage overlaps: Replace All will only replace the outer var. Keep clicking Replace or Replace All until no more replacements are done (watch the statusbar of the replace dialog).